# Gliese Catalog Designation prefixes

Tags: star-catalogues

In the Gliese catalog there are a bunch of prefixes, such as GJ, GI, Wo, etc. My question is do the numbers overlap ever? I tried to look it up, but nothing I could find was conclusive to me.

Comment: Isn't this explained by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_Catalogue_of_Nearby_Stars ?

Comment: No, it does not specifically state that numeral designations are not repeated, nor would it be a good idea to just assume they don't especially with astronomy things considering how ludicriously dumb astronomy labeling often is.

Comment: What do you mean "repeated"? Gl182 =GJ182, if that's what you mean. GJ reuses the Gl and Wo numbers unless stars are established as binaries. The wiki clearly states that the Wo supplement and then new stars in GJ used new numbers.

Comment: See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_catalogue#Gl.2C_GJ.2C_Wo for a summary.

Comment: Is GJ182 = GI182 = Wo182, etc.

Comment: There is no Wo182. See the wiki.

Comment: @RobJeffries really... I'm not asking about the existence of a Wo182. I'm asking if there was a similar designated star, as there may well be, I don't know, would those be the same stars or different stars...

Comment: "A supplement to the catalogue, published in 1970 by Richard van der Riet Woolley and associates, extended the range out to 25 parsecs (82 ly). This supplement added catalogue numbers in the range 9001–9850 using the now deprecated Wo prefix. Stars in this range now also use the GJ prefix." So GJ replaces Wo and Wo9001=GJ9001. A point of confusion is that decimal GJ numbers from CNS2 now have a (new) integer number in CNS3. Thus GJ9001=GJ4.1